# How to secure javascript browser upload to AWS S3

Tags: javascript, security, amazon-s3, upload, cors

Please forgive the noob question. I have a basic image upload script to send files to my S3 bucket:

```
<body>
  <input type="file" id="file-chooser" /> 
  <button id="upload-button">Upload to S3</button>
  <div id="results"></div>
  <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.34.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
      AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", secretAccessKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"});

      var bucket = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: 'XXXXXXXXXX'} });

      var fileChooser = document.getElementById('file-chooser');
      var button = document.getElementById('upload-button');
      var results = document.getElementById('results');
      button.addEventListener('click', function () {
          var file = fileChooser.files[0];
          if (file) {
              results.innerHTML = '';

              var params = { Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type, Body: file };
              bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
                  results.innerHTML = err ? 'ERROR!' : 'UPLOADED.';
              });
          } else {
              results.innerHTML = 'Nothing to upload.';
          }
      }, false);
  </script>
</body>
```

I have also set up CORS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

This page works correctly if I set permissions on my bucket to either Everyone or Authenticated Users and include the Access Key and Secret Key in the page code. However, exposing my keys seems like a terrible idea. And wouldn't this allow anyone with an Access Key/Secret Key pair to upload into my bucket? How can I make this more secure? Is it as simple as changing the AllowedOrigin in the CORS configuration to the IP of my website? But then I still have the keys in my code.

I have tried and failed for a couple of days using the form-POST method with an encoded policy and signature. I can get that to work without authentication (no policy), but when I try to include an encrypted policy all I get is SignatureDoesNotMatch errors. Another solution would be to use the POST method with no authorization and limit the CORS AllowedOrigin to my website IP as mentioned above. Is this too simple?

If I'm way out of my depth here please let me know. I know this is well documented by AWS but I feel like I'm missing a crucial part of this puzzle. Thanks!

Comment: Have you posted your problems getting policy signing to work correctly with `POST` uploads here on SO? Unauthenticated = bad, putting your AWS credentials in javascript = worse.  S3 has a test suite for Signature V4 that gives you the results your code should obtain at each step: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-test-suite.html